# Does there exist a one-way quantum computer?

Tags: computational-models

I'm wondering if we have managed to create a experimental version of a one-way computer and if so is there one available to "play with"  as it is the case with circuit models which are provided by ibmq etc.?

If not, is anyone aware of any simulation software that would provide classical simulation of measurement based quantum computing?

Comment: Could you use a circuit-based QC to build a cluster state, and then simulate the MBQC?

Comment: @MarkS This would be rather inefficient. Even in a more practical setup, you might want to build the cluster state column by column (and then measure the previous column etc.) while you go, this only requires a constant overhead over the # of qubits in the circuit.

Comment: @MarkS It could work for classical simulation (you could use qiskit or w/e to get something running quick but it would be very hacky, let alone how hard it would be to support qudits) When it comes to physical implementation, I think superconducting computers would not handle MBQC so well as there is necessity to do different measurements based on previous measurement results and that interaction will probably take more time than it takes qubits to decohere. When it comes to other implementations, I have no idea but I would assume it won't be very efficient